# Download ZIP file coming as the response on an api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, zip, blob

I have a binary zip file coming in as the response of an api call. I want to download that zip file directly using Javacript/React. How can I achieve this?

Comment: FYI, I am getting a binary file as the response type from the api I am hitting. I need a way to download this binary file into my local file system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post)

Answer (score 0):

Read this [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and try this function:

```
function readFile(binaryFile) {

  let reader = new FileReader();

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(binaryFile);

// in success case, do something with result
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.result);
  };

// in error case, do something with result
  reader.onerror = function() {
    console.log(reader.error);
  };

}
```

best regards!